# Probability of matching exactly 5 numbers in standard 6/49 lottery if you buy 100 tickets

Tags: statistics

In a standard 49 number lottery where 6 numbers are drawn, what is the probability of matching exactly 5 of the 6 numbers, no more no less, if you buy 100 tickets. I know that the probability of matching exactly 5 with 1 ticket is $$ \frac{{{6}\choose{5}}\cdot{{43}\choose{1}}}{{49}\choose{6}}=1.84\cdot10^{-5}$$

Comment: It will depend on how you buy the tickets.  Do you randomly choose each one (with a tiny chance of duplicates)?  Do you optimize the choices in some way?

Comment: Each ticket is randomly chosen with no duplicates. Each has a 1.84*10^-5 probability of having exactly 5 numbers matching as stated above. I initially assumed you would just multiply 1.84*10^-5 times 100 to get the total probability, but in the extreme case, if you bought a ticket for every number combination, your probability should be 1, but 1.84*10^-5 times 49C6 is 258.

Comment: If the probability of a success is $p$ then the probability of a failure is $1-p$.  With $n$ independent  attempts, the probability of no successes is $(1-p)^n$  and so the probability of at least one success is $1-(1-p)^n$.  For small $p$ and small $n$, this would be about $np- \frac{n(n-1)}{2}p^2$

Answer (score 1):

There are $N=\binom{49}{6}$ possible lottery tickets, of which $\binom{6}{5} \cdot 43$ match exactly five of the winning numbers, so there are $n_0=N-\binom{6}{5} \cdot 43$ possible tickets which do *not* match five winning numbers.  A random subset of size $100$ taken from the possible tickets contains none of the match-5 numbers with probability
$$p_0 = \frac{\binom{n_0}{100}}{\binom{N}{100}}$$
and the probability that the random subset contains at least one match-5 winner is $1-p_0$.  The numbers involved are so huge as to be difficult to compute without software, but Mathematica says $1-p_0=0.00184331$.

Given the computational difficulties, we might investigate a more tractable approximation.  The expected number of match-5 winners in the subset of $100$ is
$$\lambda = 100 \cdot \frac{\binom{6}{5} \cdot 43}{N}=0.00184499$$
If we assume the distribution of the number of winners is approximately Poisson, the probability of at least one winner is
$$1-e^{-\lambda} = 0.00184329$$
so the approximation is excellent in this case.

Answer (score 0):

How you choose the tickets will have an effect.  Just saying "randomly with no duplicates" is not precise enough.  Let's consider a simpler case first.

Consider fair, standard 6-sided dice.  The probability of getting a $6$ is $\frac{1}{6}$.  What about a $6$ in $2$ throws?  A common naive answer is $2 \times \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{3}$ but, as you have realized, it isn't that simple.  Continuing that logic would suggest that with $6$ throws, it would be certain and clearly it isn't.  The naive answer of $n \times \frac{1}{6}$ is the correct answer to a different question: what is the expected (average) number of $6$s from $n$ throws.  With $6$ throws the expected number of $6$s is $1$.  Sometimes, you won't get any but, other times, you will get two or more.

Let's be a bit more precise with out statement: what's the probability of at least one $6$ with $n$ throws?  The "at least" is the tricky bit as it cover many cases: one $6$, two $6$s, etc.  You could calculate each of these and add them up but is messy.  A simple trick is to consider the opposite: what is the probability of no $6$s in $n$ throws?  For one throw, it is $\frac{5}{6}$ and for $n$, it is $(\frac{5}{6})^n$.  Subtract that from $1$ and you have your answer.  As $n$ increases, so does the probability but the increase slows and, of course, it never goes past $1$.

For things with a low probability and few repeats, the naive answer will be close but for higher probabilities or numbers of repeats, it can be very wrong.

Now, back to your random without duplicates.  How do you do it?  Let's go back to the dice.  Throw the die once and note the number.  Now you need to cut that side of the die off and throw again.  On the $6$th throw you will have a one sided die and be sure to get the last number to complete the set.  Of course, that is not so easy so you could continue to throw a normal die but ignore the repeats and throw again.  Again, after $6$ throws, you will have the full set but only because you ignored the many repeat throws.  In reality, you probably threw the die much more than $6$ times.